# I uploaded my site to the internet, but I don't know how to attach the database to the site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=ftp.Blaz.co.il/Shim/MainProject2/App_Data/Database.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;
User Instance=True;
User Id=BB;Password=BB23
```

Where is my mistake?

The userid and the password should be the user id and the password to connect the FTP folder?

I didn't write this in my `web.config`, it's just in my DAL class.

I'm using SQL Server Express and web developer (C#)

Comment: I'm pretty damn sure that the credentials are not those you use for your FTP account. Try asking your provider for the database credentials.

Comment: you must add there the credentials who grant access to the sql server database.

Comment: I would think you need to (1) upload your MDF file to the FTP server, and then (2) **attach** that MDF to the SQL Server instance that's running on that server. You cannot just use `AttachDbFilename` and provide an FTP address.....

Comment: Also - you **cannot** define both `Integrated Security` and a `User Id/Password` combination at the same time; you need to decide which method to use - they're mutually exclusive

Comment: thank you. how do i attach that mdf to the SQL Server instance ? that is my main problem

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web provider:

- Do they host sql?
- Have you purchased that hosting package?

If you have a sql hosting package you need to use the web host's console to attach the `.mdf`.

From there you need to follow the advice above regarding connection though the web.config.

Depending on the type and amount of data you need to store it might be worth considering SQLce, this would attach in the way that you seem to be trying.